# Как добавить кнопку в ui для qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Я создал кнопку pushbutton в файле mw.h 
и создал кнопку pushbutton_2 в дизайнере.
и хочу что бы они стояли рядом и если бы я работал в дизайнере то это было бы примерно так:

```
 ui->pushbutton->move(320 100);
 ui->pushbutton_2->move(220,100);
```

но так как pushbutton я создавал не в дизайнере,то я не могу обратиться к ней через ui->

Comment: Создать кнопку и добавить в окно или в другой элемент. Поищите функцию `addWidget`. + можно получить элемент из `ui`.

Comment: addWidget вроде как работает только для слоев , а мне не хотелось бы создавать слой

Comment: Вроде [никак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989231/how-to-add-buttons-to-a-main-window-in-qt)

Comment: @gil9red, как он хотел не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К этой кнопке и не надо обращаться через ui. Обращайтесь к ней просто по указателю `pushButton->move(x, y);` Стоит только удостовериться, что родителем этой кнопки стала форма (или её потомки), которую вы сделали в дизайнере.
P.S. Совет напоследок: без крайней необходимости не пользуйтесь перемещением виджетов в абсолютную точку на форме. Пусть лучше этим занимаются компоновщики.

Comment: +1 за layout'ы / компоновщики